# In KDE Plasma, how to group presented windows by app, like on macOS MissionControl?

Tags: kde, window, plasma, effects, presentation

I have a hot-corner action assigned for "Present Windows - Current Desktop" (under System Settings > Screen Edges) and it works well. However, the preview can quickly get too chaotic and confusing when you have 10 windows of Firefox, 5 windows of Dolphin and several other windows of different apps open at once.

On macOS, Mission Control solves this problem by grouping windows of the same app in groups .

[image]

How can I achieve a similar effect with KDE Plasma?